# Python matplotlib how to clear previous drawing point?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

My code is present below. I expect the during the animation, each frame only draws one point which should be in the head of the line, but in fact all the previous point are shown. It seems each time the plt only adds point to the drawing, how to change that to make it clear previous point?[all the red point are shown which is not wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX0ws.png), the df is list below for reference.

0.0 0.0

0.26 186780.0

0.27 197556.0

0.53 519439.0

0.54 533579.0

0.8 946285.0

0.81 960288.0

1.07 1306550.0

1.08 1320020.0

1.34 1642600.0

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation,rc
import pandas as pd

fig = plt.figure()
df=pd.read_csv('radialforce.csv', sep=';',skipinitialspace=True,na_values=" 
NaN")
df.dropna(axis="columns", how="any", inplace=True)
df.columns.values[1] = 'Y'


def animate(n):
    plt.plot(df['X'][:n], df['Y'][:n],color='g',lw='0.5')
    plt.scatter(df['X'][n], df['Y'][n],10,facecolor='r',edgecolor='r')    
    return fig

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,frames=len(df['X']), 
interval=100)
plt.show()
```

Comment: And each frame the drawing is like: first, the point shows, then the line connects to the point. What I expect is that the drawing likes a snake growing all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to redraw everything each iteration. Instead you want to update the line and scatter.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation,rc
import pandas as pd

fig = plt.figure()
df=pd.read_csv(...)
df.dropna(axis="columns", how="any", inplace=True)
df.columns.values[1] = 'Y'

line, = plt.plot(df['X'][:1], df['Y'][:1],color='g',lw='0.5')
scatter = plt.scatter(df['X'][0], df['Y'][0],10,facecolor='r',edgecolor='r')    

def animate(n):
    x,y=df['X'][:n+1], df['Y'][:n+1]
    line.set_data(x,y)
    scatter.set_offsets([df['X'][n], df['Y'][n]])
    plt.gca().relim()
    plt.gca().autoscale_view()

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,frames=len(df['X']), interval=100)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. There are few questions: why you put a ',' after line? and because the line shape is also need to be shown, so I try to redraw the line in each iteration but only update the point, and it works. But I still don't understand why redraw point (the scatter) doesn't clear previous points, is that the default behaviour?

Comment: To correct my comment, it seems the line.set_data don't rescale the limit, and when I try to set the limit, the plot seems strange. but when I put line plot in the animate function, it works.

Comment: The `,` is because the plot function returns a list of lines and here you only want the first item (even if there is a single line, the return value is a list).